# want to add two different tables(classes) in one hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have this code

```
ArrayList<String> city = 'Anniston';

Criteria  crit = session.createCriteria(CandidateResumeInfo.class);
 crit.add(Restrictions.eq("resumeSearchable", 1));
```

Now I want to add below criteria

`crit.add(Restrictions.in("cities", city));`

but the problem is that cities column is not in `CandidateResumeInfo.class` its in CandidateInfo Class.

Any idea how to add this criteria as well in the above one,how to add `CandidateInfo` class as well in the above criteria.

guess i need to do join or link these two tables but how, and will there be any changes in the entity classes?

These are my 2 classes

```
@Entity

@Table(name="candidateinfo")

public class CandidateInfo implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String city;
    private String stateProvince;
    private String zip;
    private String country;
    private Set candidateVideos = new HashSet();

    private String yearsOfExperience;
    private String loginName;
    private String password;
    private String address;
    private String emailAddress;
    private int passwordResetQuestionId;
    private String passwordResetAnswer;
    private String middleName;

    private String homeEveningPhone;
    private String workDayPhone;
    private boolean videoSubmited;
    private boolean resumeSubmited;
    private String cellPhone;
    private String availability=null;
    private String workStatus=null;

    private String desiredSalary=null;
    private String currentJobLevel=null;
    private String currentJobTitle=null;
    private String targetJobTitle=null;
    private String alternateTargetJobTitle1=null;
    private String alternateTargetJobTitle2=null;
    private String targetJobType=null;
    private String eventType=null;

    private String joinDate = null;
    private String lastLoginDate = null;

    //private SkillsBean skillsInfo;
    private Set skills = new HashSet();
    private Set candidateResumes = new HashSet();
    private Set targetJobCategoriesId = new HashSet();
    private Set targetJobLocationsId = new HashSet();


    public CandidateInfo() {
    }
    @Column(name="userid")
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Column(name="loginname")
    public String getLoginName() {
        return loginName;
    }

    public void setLoginName(String loginName) {
        this.loginName = loginName;
    }
    @Column(name="password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    @Column(name="address")
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


............................................................................

@Entity

@Table(name="candidateresumeinfo")

public class CandidateResumeInfo implements Serializable{

    private int resumeId;
    private int candidate_userId;
    private String resumeFileLocation;
    private int resumeSearchable;
    private Date lastUpdateDate;
    private String resumeTitle;
    private String resumeText;
    private String skills;
    private int rowCount;


    @Column(name="resumeSearchable")
    public int isResumeSearchable() {
        return resumeSearchable;
    }
    public void setResumeSearchable(int resumeSearchable) {
        this.resumeSearchable = resumeSearchable;
    }
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue 
    @Column(name="resumeid")
    public int getResumeId() {
        return resumeId;
    }

    public void setResumeId(int resumeId) {
        this.resumeId = resumeId;
    }
    @Column(name="candidate_userid")
    public int getCandidate_userId() {
        return candidate_userId;
    }
    public void setCandidate_userId(int candidate_userId) {
        this.candidate_userId = candidate_userId;
    }
    @Column(name="resumelocation")
    public String getResumeFileLocation() {
        return resumeFileLocation;
    }

    public void setResumeFileLocation(String resumeFileLocation) {
        this.resumeFileLocation = resumeFileLocation;
    }

    @Column(name="resumetitle")
    public String getResumeTitle() {
        return resumeTitle;
    }
    public void setResumeTitle(String resumeTitle) {
        this.resumeTitle = resumeTitle;
    }
    @Column(name="resumetext")
    public String getResumeText() {
        return resumeText;
    }
    public void setResumeText(String resumeText) {
        this.resumeText = resumeText;
    }

    public void setLastUpdateDate(Date lastUpdateDate) {
        this.lastUpdateDate = lastUpdateDate;
    }
    @Column(name="lastUpdateDate")
    public Date getLastUpdateDate() {
        return lastUpdateDate;
    }
    @Column(name="skills")
    public String getSkills() {
        return skills;
    }

    public void setSkills(String skills) {
        this.skills = skills;
    }
    @Transient
    public int getRowCount() {
        return rowCount;
    }

    public void setRowCount(int count) {
        this.rowCount = count;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u need to add relation like

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public CandidateResumeInfo getCandidateResumeInfo () {
    return this.candidateResumeInfo ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I need to add this statement in my CandidateIndfo class ? Do i need to write any statement in CandidateResumeInfo class as well?          and the code i have written above in my question ,do i need to write any thing else there , where i will define that from where this cities column belongs to                         Thanks

Comment: [look here for example][1]


  [1]: http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-tutorial/hibernate-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

Have the many-to-one association from `CandidateResumeInfo` to `CandidateInfo`.

Add new member in `CandidateResumeInfo` class say,

```
@ManyToOne()  
@JoinColumn(name = "candidate_userId")  
private CandidateInfo candidateInfo;  

// Also add getters and setters
```

Now in the query, add a new alias,

```
crit.createAlias("candidateInfo", "candidateInfo");  
crit.add(Restrictions.in("candidateInfo.city", city));
```